# SQLClient Command Parameter Query String Length

Tags: string, vb.net, sqlclient

I am connecting to a SQL Server and am trying to limit the results by adding parameters.  The first parameter I added, @sdate, worked just fine.  But, now I am trying to add a second parameter which is not working.  I want the field, LP_EOC_DATA.PL, to only be returned if the length of the string is greater than 6 characters long.  The code below executed, and like I say, the dates returned were correct, but it also returned values from LP_EOC_DATA.PL that had string lengths less than 6.  Please let me know if you know how to get this to work.  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub doSQL()
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim sqlString As String = "SELECT LP_EOC_DATA.PL as PLs, LP_EOC_DATA.cDate as ReadDate, LP_EOC_LOV.LOCATION as Location " &
        "FROM LP_EOC_DATA INNER JOIN LP_EOC_LOV ON LP_EOC_DATA.PIC = LP_EOC_LOV.PIC " &
        "WHERE LP_EOC_DATA.cDate > (@sdate) AND LEN(LP_EOC_DATA.PL) > @slen1 " &
        "UNION SELECT dbo.VT_DATA.PL as PLs, dbo.VT_DATA.cDate as ReadDate, dbo.VT_LOV.LOCATION as Location " &
        "FROM dbo.VT_DATA INNER JOIN dbo.VT_LOV ON dbo.VT_DATA.PIC = dbo.VT_LOV.PIC " &
        "WHERE dbo.VT_DATA.cDate > (@sdate) AND LEN(dbo.VT_DATA.PL) > @slen1 " &
        "ORDER BY ReadDate;"

    myConn = New SqlConnection("SERVER=ServerName;UID=uName;" &
                            "PWD=Password;")
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = sqlString
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slen1", 6)
    'myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rx1", "'%[^0-9a-z]%'")
    'myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rx2", " dbo.VT_DATA.PL NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-z]%'")

    myConn.Open()
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
    Table.Load(myReader)

    DataGridView1.Visible = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table
    lblTotal.Text = Table.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Also, as you can see, I am looking to add another parameter that only returns alphanumeric results from the same LP_EOC_DATA.PL field.  I haven't got quite that far yet, but if you see something I'm doing wrong there too, I'd appreciate the input.

Comment: I suggest that you do yourself a favour and create that SQL as a stored procedure so that you can format it to be easily readable. Or at least use an XML literal: [Is there something better than a StringBuilder for big blocks of SQL in the code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/86286/175972).

Comment: Oh, and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Reading ahead a bit in the code comments, Sql Server doesn't do real RegEx. Trying to match a `LIKE` with a regular expression is _not going to end well_. You should also know that parameters are **never** substituted directly into the sql command string. _You can't put code into a parameter value_. It will just treat it like a long string.

Comment: Most of my experience is with Excel VBA.  So this VB.net stuff is pretty new to me.  Thanks for the suggestion about the SQL as a stored procedure.  Also, why should I not use AddWithValue, and what should I be doing instead?

Comment: @RobLego The comment about AddWithValue has a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you format your SQL a little more. There's some structure, but it still comes off as a big wall of text. It's even harder for us to debug than it is for you, since we don't know your schema at all. There are also a number of other little things you should do different before we even address the question (`Using` block so connection is closed in case of exception, avoid AddWithValue() for index safety, isolate SQL from user interface, etc):

```
Function doSQL(StartDate As DateTime) As DataTable
    Dim result As New DataTable
    Dim sqlString As String = _
        "SELECT LP_EOC_DATA.PL as PLs, LP_EOC_DATA.cDate as LPRReadDate, LP_EOC_LOV.LOCATION as Location " & 
        "FROM LP_EOC_DATA " & 
        "INNER JOIN LP_EOC_LOV ON LP_EOC_DATA.PIC = LP_EOC_LOV.PIC " & 
        "WHERE LP_EOC_DATA.cDate > @sdate AND LEN(COALESCE(LP_EOC_DATA.PL,'')) > @slen1 " &
        "UNION " & 
        "SELECT dbo.VT_DATA.PL as PLs, dbo.VT_DATA.cDate as ReadDate, dbo.VT_LOV.LOCATION as LPRLocation " &
        "FROM dbo.VT_DATA " &
        "INNER JOIN dbo.VT_LOV ON dbo.VT_DATA.PIC = dbo.VT_LOV.PIC " &
        "WHERE dbo.VT_DATA.cDate > @sdate AND LEN(COALESCE(dbo.VT_DATA.PL,'')) > @slen1 " &
        "ORDER BY ReadDate;"

    Using myConn As New SqlConnection("SERVER=ServerName;UID=uName;" &
                            "PWD=Password;"), _
          myCmd As New SqlCommand(sqlString, myConn)

        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@sdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StarDate
        myCmd.Parameters.Add("@slen1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 6

        myConn.Open()
        result.Load(myCmd.ExecuteReader())
    End Using

    Return result
End Function
```

And then call it like this:

```
Dim tbl As DataTable = doSql(DateTimePicker1.Value)
DataGridView1.Visible = True
DataGridView1.DataSource = tbl
lblTotal.Text = tbl.Rows.Count
```

As for the question, there are a few possibilities: `NULL` values can give unexpected results in this kind of situation (the code I posted already accounts for that). You may also have trouble with certain unicode whitespace padding your character count. Another possibility is `char` or `nchar` fields instead of `varchar` or `nvarchar`, though I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I adjusted my code to reflect the changes you made.  Unfortunately, it is still returning results from LP_EOC_DATA.PL and VT_DATA.PL that are fewer than 7 characters long.  I'm not sure what kind of datatype it is.  I didn't create the database.  The values in those fields are alphanumeric and can be as long as 30 characters. The values can also contain "[" and "]" which I will want to filter out as well eventually.

Comment: I noticed that the results that I am getting that are wrong are all numbers.  That is to say, if the field is alphanumeric, then the parameter will work.  So "AA2" won't show up.  But, if the value is 314, then it will be returned.

Comment: There's not even any need to use concatenation, so the SQL code can be even clearer. XML literals allow you to just write the code as you would in SSMS and the most recent VB version supports multiline literals so it's even easier.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, can you give me an example of how to use XML literals?  I'm researching it through searches but a little example with the code I have would be super helpful.

Comment: I've provided an XML literal example in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question per se but a reply to the request for an XML literal example. As that requires a few lines of code, I'd rather not put it in a comment.

```
Dim sql = <sql>
              SELECT *
              FROM MyTable
              WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn
          </sql>
Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql.Value, connection)
```

Note that the element name can be anything you want but I usually use 'sql' when it's for SQL code.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've found examples like that, but I'm still confused on how to use this with my data.  For example, I'm not using SELECT *.  Do I still write 'SELECT LP_EOC_DATA.PL as PLS'?  Is it all essentially the same code, just wrapped in the <sql></sql> tags?

Comment: I think that you're trying to complicate this. Using an XML literal is just a way to make the SQL code easier to read by alleviating the need for extraneous characters like double-quotes and ampersands. It's just a way to create a `String` containing the SQL code. You would write your SQL between the opening and closing XML tags exactly as you would write it in SSMS.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it to work and I even incorporated string interpolation to make it even cleaner.  That is much better.

Comment: Not a fan of xml literals. A lot of unnecessary extra stuff happens at runtime to support this. I also don't like VB's multi-line string literals, because you either end up with a bunch of extra whitespace or breaking the indentation level in the source code. The extra `&` to concatenate on each line aren't that much work, and the concat operations are optimized away by the compiler. What I'd **_really_** love to see is special support in Visual Studio for SQL literals that give you syntax highlighting for the Sql statement but only produce a string instead of an object when compiled.

Comment: It certainly would be nice to have dedicated support for inline SQL, as far as extra whitespace is concerned in XML literals and multiline `String` literals (both VB and C#), it's not ideal but it's not inherently an issue in this and many other cases. As for extra stuff at run time, again, it's not inherently an issue. Personally, I would consider readability and maintainability of code to be more important unless performance is noticeably affected. I've lost count of the number of times I've seen people omit spaces or the like when concatenating many literals. No approaches are wrong though.